# SQL WHERE COLUMN#1 = COLUMN#2 IF COLUMN#2 = 'Whatever'

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

SQL -> `WHERE COLUMN#1 = COLUMN#2 IF COLUMN#2 = 'Whatever'`

In other words, I want to see all States and Cities within that State, if State contains a City that has a River running through it.

BTW. `WHERE COLUMN#2 = 'Whatever'` will not work, as I need all of the Cities in that State.

How does one write this?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Please add some simple data and expected results. A few rows will suffice to show what you want.

Comment: I think you'll need subqueries for this: query 1 to find a list of states which contain at least one city with RiverRunsThroughIt = 1, and then query 2 to list all cities where state is in the output of the query 1. Can you see how to write query 1 at least?

Comment: You will most likely get some helpful answers once you tell some more about your tables (for example table names and column names). Meanwhile, I am curious to know what could possibly be the reason to find all the cities of a state if just 1 (or more) city in that state has a river running through it?

Comment: Thanks Rup. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rup. I'll do that.

> I think you'll need subqueries for this: query 1 to find a list of states which contain at >least one city with RiverRunsThroughIt = 1, and then query 2 to list all cities where >state is in the output of the query 1